# Cumulative sum of average daily plan from month with measure for each day in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

There are problem with calculating and visualizating plan values in report.

I have monthly plans and daily facts and want to compare it on a chart like this:

[image: plan and fact]

My data looks like this:

| Plan date | Category1 | Plan value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2023 | toys | 2000.20 |
| 01.01.2023 | instruments | 4020.32 |
| 01.02.2023 | toys | 3200.12 |

Only thing I came up is get average daily plan from month plan (divide month plan value to count of days in month) for each day and get cumulative sum of it.

I tried do it with DAX:

```
Plan daily AVG := 
CALCULATE(
    [Plan value] / [Count of days in month]
    ,ALLSELECTED(DimDate[Date])
)

Plan cumulative sum := 
CALCULATE(
    [Plan daily AVG]
    ,FILTER(
         ALL(DimDate)
        ,DimDate[Date] <= MAX(DimDate[Date])
    )
)
```

but my measures works only on month level:
[image]